# Return a view from controller with a JSON string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. After user authentication in my app I am redirecting to a `controller/action`. In that action I am getting some json data from a service.

I would like to pass that string data to a view and then manipulate the json with javascript. Note:I am talking about a string, not a model. In Webforms,

I would typically have a page-scoped string variable like: `string _json`. Then I would set that var to the json returned by my service. And then in my markup page I would have:

```
<script>
    var data = <%_json%>;
    etc.. 
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this in ASP.NET MVC?:

Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    string data = await _myService.GetList();
    return View(model); //here I want my view to know about data
}
```

View

```
<script>
   var json = @data //something like this?
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you pass a string and not a model?

Comment: Because I want json on the client as a data source for a jquery grid widget. Also, this data is coming from a 3rd party api call so it's already a string. I just need to pipe it to the view. I will try what the others suggest and see if it works. thanks

Comment: The parse the string to an object and pass the model to the view (or parse it in the client using `JSON.parse())`

Comment: Why should I go to the trouble of creating a model and deserializing this perfectly valid string of json when it's what I need on the client anyway?

Comment: You have to de-serialize/parse it somewhere - a `string` on its own is no use to you :)

Comment: When I say: $("#mything").gowidget({datasource: {data: @data}});

This @data string is pretty useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122800/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mattomk).

Answer (score 1):

Change controller code to :

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Index()
{
  string data = await _myService.GetList();
  return Json(new
        {
            JsonData = data ,
            Status = true
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `GetList` method returns a correct json string then simply use [`ViewBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag):

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.SomeData = await _myService.GetList();
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
<script>
   var json = @ViewBag.SomeData ; 
</script>
```

In other case you should implement another method which will result in correct json string, for example @Sarang version will return the correct string. Usage of it:

```
<script>
   var json = @Html.Action("YourMethod", "YourController") ; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change controller code to :

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Index()
{
    string data = await _myService.GetList();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works too. Model as a string object

```
<script>
   var data = @Html.Raw(Model)
</script>
```